# Set description on DataContract members

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, serialization

I would like to control whats on the help pages, and especially information about each field that. For example, I have this class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "MH")]
public class MessageHeader 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "I")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "CI")]
    public Guid ChannelId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "CR")]
    public double Created { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "CTI")]
    public int ContentTypeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "S")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "EC")]
    public bool Encrypted { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "E")]
    public double Expire { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to add the DescriptionAttribute but it does not show on the help page. Any idea how to add description to each field?

Comment: You're looking to control what's output to the metadata page for your service? Or documentation?

Comment: Meta data page, the auto-generated help page for the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this, but you may be able to enhance the WSDL using a CustomContractConverter. Here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlcontractconversioncontext.aspx) for the converter, its certianly not as simple as an attribute, but because there is no description provided by default for DataContracts, this may be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a documentation tool like [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/documentation), current release [here](http://sandcastlestyles.codeplex.com/).

This automatically creates documentation files from your code and code comments:

> **Project Description**
>   Sandcastle produces accurate, MSDN style,
>   comprehensive documentation by reflecting over the source assemblies
>   and optionally integrating XML Documentation Comments. Sandcastle has
>   the following key features:
>
> - *Works with or without authored comments*

To get you started, here is a "[5-minute Sandcastle tutorial: build C# code documentation](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/09/build-html-documentation-for-y.html)" (Andrew Stellman, O'Reilly Community).